# Regex in Jquery Selectors

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex which

**does not allows a  number to come before or after a number like.**

I have `id`s like this

```
abcd-1
abcd-11
abcd-21
...
abcd-91
```

I can't figure out how to write a regex that

**gives me the element that have only 1**

I mean `abcd-1` (having no digit before and after 1). I am doing something like this

```
$("[id$=1]")
```

which **gives me all the the elements from `abcd-1` to `abcd-91`**. I just neeed `abcd-1`.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There exists a regex filter to elements selectors that you need to append to jquery:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

You can then use it as below:

```
// Select all elements with an ID starting a vowel:
$(':regex(id,^[aeiou])');

// Select all DIVs with classes that contain numbers:
$('div:regex(class,[0-9])');

// Select all SCRIPT tags with a SRC containing jQuery:
$('script:regex(src,jQuery)');
```

In your case the following shall match:

```
 $(':regex(id,\w*-1)');
```

Or you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with just jquery:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/\w*-1/);
    }).click(function(){ //your click event code here });
```

Comment: will that allow me to find the element having is `abcd-1` and not all of them

Comment: You can create a regular expression to match anything you need, I have added the one that matches your case

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a regex in a selector. (Not with just the base jQuery library, anyway.)

But you don't need regex to implement what you are describing. You are already using the "attribute ends with" selector, which finds all elements ending with the specified text without regard for what came before that text.

How about searching for ids ending in `-1`? As in:

```
$("[id$='-1']")
```

That will match the `abcd-1` element you asked about, but not `abcd-91`.

Comment: would it solve the problem because I have no id that is ending with -1

Comment: Yes you do. You said you want to select an element with the id `abcd-1`, which clearly *does* end in `-1`.